# Why using yield instead of return in pytest fixtures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I see why using `yield` keyword when we want to run our tests and then clean things up going back to the fixture and running some code after the `yield` statement. As the code below.

```
@pytest.fixture
def sending_user(mail_admin):
    user = mail_admin.create_user()
    yield user
    mail_admin.delete_user(user)
```

However why is it necessary to use `yield` when we only want to return an object and don't comeback to the fixture, returning a `patch` for example?

```
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open
from pytest import raises, fixture
import os.path

def read_from_file(file_path):
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        raise Exception("File does not exists!")
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()[0]

@fixture()
def mock_open_file():
    with patch("builtins.open", new_callable=mock_open, read_data="Correct string") as mocked:
        yield mocked #instead of: return mocked

@fixture()
def mock_os():
    with patch("os.path.exists", return_value=True) as mocked:
        yield mocked #instead of: return mocked

def test_read_file_and_returns_the_correct_string_with_one_line(mock_os, mock_open_file):
    result = read_from_file("xyz")
    mock_open_file.assert_called_once_with("xyz", "r")
    assert result == "Correct string"

def test_throws_exception_when_file_doesnt_exist(mock_os, mock_open_file):
    mock_os.return_value = False
    with raises(Exception):
        read_from_file("xyz")
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter.  And it's simpler to just always use `yield` than to worry about if now or ever in the future someone's going to add cleanup.

Comment: The thing is, I wrote some tests and using `yield` it works but not using `return`.

Comment: if your method is expected to `yield` then a consumer might call `next(mock_open_file())` even when expecting a single result. This would fail if you did a return.

Comment: @FrankYellin @JonSG I just updated the question containing the entire piece of code. In both fixtures, if I change to `return` it fails.

Comment: That's because you are in a context manager (`with` clause), and if you use `return`, the control is not returned to the fixture and the cleanup of the context manager is not called (e.g. the patching is not reverted). This can have any unwanted side effects and wil likely fail other tests. So, as @FrankYellin wrote: just use always `yield` in a fixture, so you won't run into this kind of problem.